# How do I go to a link after 5 seconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

How would I make it so after a certain amount of time, a script will link to lets say href="index.jpg" rel="lightbox" class="blah";

Then soon after go to the next link after another 5 seconds etc..

Comment: Are you changing a link on a page after 5 seconds or trying to redirect the user to another page after 5 seconds?

Comment: From what I gather, your question is not being asked correctly at all. You should be asking how to cycle through a bunch of lightbox-enabled images  without requiring a user to click, much like a slide show.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) function to implement this:

> Executes a code snippet or a function after specified delay.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it once use setTimeout. if you want to do it over and over use setInterval

This example will call myfunc() after 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds)

```
setTimeout("myfunc()", 5000);

function myfunc()
{
   // do what you need to do here
}
```